# Listing active streaming sessions ( tvheadend, jellyfin )

Tags: bash, jellyfin

I'm writing a shutdown script for my mediaserver I'm running TVHeadend and Jellyfin on. Is there any way to list if there are streams actively being viewed on the server?

I'd like to:

· Know if and how many clients are connected (and streaming) to TVHeadend

· Know if and how many clients are connected (and streaming) to Jellyfin

· Know if there are any ssh or rsync sessions in progress.

The purpose is just to determine if a shutdown is possible at a given time.

Best regards